# How to align a label on a line in Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap5-modal

I added a modal and I would like the label to be on one line. I guess I need to reduce the input and increase the width of the label.

But... Do you know how to do this on Bootstrap? I'm lost in my divs.

[image]

Below, here is an idea of my current code:

Thank you for your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Simple modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="modal.hide()">
    </button>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="cliente" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-end">Quantité a transférer</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cliente">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="endereco" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-end">Changement Bénéficiaire Économique</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="complemento" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-end">Compte du destinataire</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complemento">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your tags to have just one version. Also, have you read [the grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#grid-options)? It's all spelled out quite clearly there how to size columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a grid system, where the entire screen is divided into 12 columns. You assign each label 2 columns, and each input box 10 columns, using the classes `col-sm-2` and `col-sm-10`. If you change the numbers there, you can change how many columns each field takes up. For example, if you change the label class to `col-sm-4' and the input class to 'col-sm-8', the label will take up 1/3 of the screen (4/12 columns) and the input will take up 2/3 of the screen (8/12 columns). You can change these numbers to get a value that works for you.

The sample below shows 3 different values for the amount of columns, so you can see how this works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Simple modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="modal.hide()">
    </button>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="cliente" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-end">Quantité a transférer</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cliente">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="endereco" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-end">Changement Bénéficiaire Économique</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="complemento" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label text-end">Compte du destinataire</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complemento">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```